# rails nasted model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model association like this

**post.rb**

*title:string   description:text*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :items

end
```

**item.rb**

*post_id:integer order:integer*

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_one :link
  has_one :movie
  has_one :photo
  has_one :quate
end
```

**link, movie, photo, quate.rb**

*link.rb : item_id:integer url:string url-text:string*

*movie.rb : item_id:integer youtube-url:string*

*photo.rb : item_id:integer image:string comment:string title:string*

*quate.rb : item_id:integer quate:string q-url:string q-title:string*

```
  belongs_to :item
```

I want to build user-post application by ruby on rails.
Item model has order column ,so user can choose and add whatever movie, link , photo to build there own post.

How can I build form for these nasted models?

Comment: Rails Cast has a great episode on this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised.  I believe you have to be a subscriber to watch that one, but the older one is free to watch: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: You mean "nasty model"?

Comment: Someone uploaded all the pro editions to YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amT27SfNhKM

Answer (score 0):

This might not be as defined as you need; I'll delete if required.

You have a huge [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) with your `belongs_to` models. They look like they represent a single data-set, and I would merge them into the `Item` model, using an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to differentiate their state:

```
#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   #schema id | post_id | state | url | title | comment | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :post
   enum state: [:link, :movie, :photo, :quate]
end
```

This will give you the ability to create instances of `Item`, which you can then assign different "states":

```
@item = Item.new
@item.state = :link
```

---

Although it means changing your pattern, it gives you the ability to store `items` for each `post` directly (instead of having to append them with another model):

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @post = Post.new
      @post.items.build
   end

   def create
      @post = Post.new post_params
      @post.save
   end

   private

   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(items_attributes: [:state, :url, :title, :comment])
   end
end

#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :items do |i| %>
       <%= i.select :state, Item.states.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}) %>
       <%= i.text_field :url %>
       <%= i.text_field :title %>
       <%= i.text_field :comment %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You also need to make sure you have [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your `Post` model:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```